# How can I restrict the respositories for specified users?

Tags: linux, svn, apache-2.2

I´m a newbie in linux, and I configured my subversion using a lot of tutorials on the internet.

My subversion uses webdav and I add my users using the command:

```
htpasswd /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd userb
```

My dav_svn.conf contains follow configuration:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

In the directory /svn I was created some repositories like /svn/test or /svn/chat.

My Question is: How can I restrict the respositories for specified users? Because all the users have permissions in all the repositories.

Answer (score 4):

add the following line below AuthuserFile

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/svn/conf/authz
```

Of cource change the path to your svn root to point to the authz file.. Then it might look like

```
[groups]
admin = user
devteam = user,user2,user3

[/]
@devteam = r
@admin = rw

[/some_repo]
@devteam = rw
@admin = rw
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Mike's answer from before, *if* you want the future capability to [let users edit their own SVN access through a Trac plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SvnAuthzAdminPlugin) or similar, you could also give each SVN project its own Authz file. All my projects' SVN settings are held in separate files, one per project. Something like:

```
<Location /svn/projectname>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /usr/local/svn/projectname
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/authz/projectname
    ...
</Location>
```

This would be a pain to manage manually, so you'd want some sort of configuration management software on the SVN server, or your own scripts to generate the separate Locations.